# How to instruct cmdargs to not parse args beyond some point?

Tags: haskell, command-line-arguments, haskell-cmdargs

I am working on a program that takes another command with its arguments:

```
$ myprog record -f 1.txt ls
$ myprog record -f 1.txt ls -l
```

Something like sudo:

```
$ sudo ls
$ sudo ls -l
```

Here is my code that uses cmdargs:

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
-- stack --resolver lts-9.20 script --package cmdargs

{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}

module Main where

import           System.Console.CmdArgs as Args

data Tape = Record  {file :: Maybe String, command :: String, commandArgs :: [String]}
          | Replay
            deriving (Data, Typeable, Show, Eq)
main :: IO ()
main = do
  m <- cmdArgs $ modes
         [ Record  { file        = def &= typ "FILE"
                   , command     = def &= typ "COMMAND" &= argPos 0
                   , commandArgs = def &= typ "ARGS"    &= args     }
         , Replay ]
  print m
```

It works nicely, but only for commands that don't have their own flags:

```
$ ./cmdargs.hs record -f 1.txt ls
Record {file = Just "1.txt", command = "ls", commandArgs = []}

$ ./cmdargs.hs record -f 1.txt ls 1 2 3
Record {file = Just "1.txt", command = "ls", commandArgs = ["1","2","3"]}

$ ./cmdargs.hs record -f 1.txt ls -l
Unknown flag: -l
```

Q: How to instruct cmdargs to keep "commandArgs" as is, without looking for flags in it?

Answer (score 3):

The traditional method is not within the parser but using a `--` argument, indicating the end of flags:

```
$ ./args record -- something -l
Record {file = Nothing, command = "something", commandArgs = ["-l"]}
```

Unfortunately I don't know how to tell getArgs to do so at an arbitrary place, but I imagine it would have something to do with modes.